# Tapped Delay Line channel model in wireless communication

Tags: channel-estimation

Can someone explain the difference between tdl (Tapped Delay Line) -a , tdl-b and tdl-c and their use cases?

Comment: I've never heard of those TDL variations. Can you provide more details? Also, edit your question to make it as specific as you can, instead of asking for a complete explanation that ends up only repeating what may already be there in textbooks.

Comment: This basically is used in Matlab 5G toolbox for creating a multipath propagation channel model
But Matlab has a few variations of these tdl models which are mentioned above..All I now at this point of time is that they all are used for Non line of sight communication
But couldn't find the exact differences between the same

Comment: I'd suggest asking MathWorks for support, then.